# HTML How can I get a full bottom border of an image where I can put text in

Tags: html, css

I'm a noob in HTML and coding in general so this might look bad, sorry about that. I'd like to have a thick border under my picture where my text would be ON the border, kinda like this :

[image: **Like this**]

Here is what I have, I managed to get the text inside the border but I can't get it to do what I want...

```css
.img {
  width: 420px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/White-tailed_deer.jpg" style="width: 420px;">
  <p style="text-align: center"> Picture of a deer </p>
</div>
```

I searched a lot on this site, I looked at some guides about borders but I didn't found how to solve this particular problem. Maybe there is a precise term for this that could've helped me to find better results and I'm sorry if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a background:

```css
.img {
  width: 420px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="img margin">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/White-tailed_deer.jpg" style="width: 420px;">
  <p style="text-align: center"> Picture of a deer </p>
</div>
```

Or if you want to work with border, make the bottom one bigger and use negative margin on text so that it goes above the border:

```css
.img {
  width: 420px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  border-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-width:50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}
p {
 margin-bottom:-40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img margin">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/White-tailed_deer.jpg" style="width: 420px;">
  <p style="text-align: center"> Picture of a deer </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is perfect, I'm sorry this looks so obvious now... thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the figure tag.

```css
figure {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png" alt="An awesome picture">
  <figcaption>MDN Logo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking about but another way of doing it.

Comment: I will use the other answer for this project since I understand it better but I tried yours and I actually learned something, so, thanks a lot